# how to extract model object from form in template using django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a formset.  I want to extract out the id of the model object that each form in the set represents.

This is because I plan to use a template tag to pass this id to a function and return a related object.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for each in model_formset %}
    {{each.instance.id}}
{% endfor %}
```